# grails date format in English language

Tags: grails, simpledateformat

I have the following code to format the date:

```
def currentDate = new Date().format('E, dd MMM yyyy')
```

The format is as I expected, however it is written in the language of my computer.
How can I get it to give the date in English?
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running in context of a Controller I would suggest you use

```
def currentDate = new Date()

def formattedDate = g.formatDate(date:currentDate, format: 'E, dd MMM yyyy')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard date formatter:

```
import java.text.*
import java.util.Locale

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat('E, dd MMM yyyy', Locale.US)
formatter.format(new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in a controller, taglib or GSP, try using the [formatDate](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatDate.html) tag instead.

```
g.formatDate(date: new Date(), format: 'E, dd MMM yyyy', locale: Locale.ENGLISH)
```

In a GSP you can also invoke it using this tag syntax:

```
<g:formatDate date="${new Date()}" format='E, dd MMM yyyy', locale="${Locale.ENGLISH}"/>
```