# g:formatDate alternative in a service

Tags: date, grails, service, date-format

Can I somehow format a date in a way similar to how g:formatDate tag is doing this, but in Service? Including i18n and l10n?

It may not be the best practice to do this in a Service, as this should be more likely part of the view logic, but I need to return a date as a part of the JSON response and I don't want to deal with this in JS (mainly because of l10n).

Thanks for advice.

Comment: You can use the same formatDate method from the controller if you will. Here is the post explaining it. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095086/grails-date-format-in-english-language) Also if you need it from the service you can still access g using the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777640/using-g-render-in-a-grails-service)

Comment: It might be possible to use g.* tags from Controller. However AFAIK taglibs cannot be used from services -- and that's something I need much more right now (I will remove controller from the question). Thanks anyway

Comment: look at this post for accessing g in the service if you really want to use formatDate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777640/using-g-render-in-a-grails-service

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but this will do for now. Thank you.
Can you please post this comment as a separate answer so I can accept it? Or edit this one...

Comment: @pseudo did you checked the Don's answer in that link? Doesn't seems to be not elegant. Also you need to think - "I really need to call this tag in a service?"

Comment: I updated my answer, thanks

Comment: @SérgioMichels Yes, ofc I did and having the option to inject tagLib directly into service attribute would be more elegant. Also you are asking if I need to do it like this? Have you read my question? In short -- yes, I do and I think that in this particular case it is either pull a little bit of view logic into service or somehow deal with the date localization on the client side and there is no good solution for that.

Comment: Using the g.dateFormat(date: date) in the controller is fine if we're outputting json directly from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use formatDate in a service or controller like that:

```
g.formatDate( date: new Date(), type: "date", style:"MEDIUM" )
```

**EDIT:**
Doesn't work in services

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options here, that don't involve pulling in the tagLib bean from the grails application.

**Option 1:**
If you're not too worried about i18n
Format the date in the service using default groovy methods.

```
static final String DATE_FORMAT = 'dd-MM-yyyy'
// ...
Date date = new Date()
String formattedDate = date.format(DATE_FORMAT)
```

(That's all you need, no extra imports)

**Option 2:**
If you are worried about i18n and still want to format the date in the service, then you can get the default date format

But first you need to get the Locale in the service, (this is where alarm bells should start ringing)

```
// Don't do this...
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
// ...
String locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()
// Don't do that ^^^
```

This gets the Locale associated with the current thread, if any, or the system default Locale else. But we want the user's locale from the request or the session.

(Those alarm bells should be joined by red flashing lights now)

But if you do want to do this, then pass the request in from the controller via the method call.

Then you can use

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils
// ...
def locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)
```

So we have the locale, and now we can get the message

```
// include the grailsApplication bean in the service
def grailsApplication
// ...

// Get the date format
def dateFormat = grailsApplication.mainContext.getMessage('default.date.format', null, 'dd-MM-yyyy', locale)

// Then you can use the groovy default method
String formattedDate = date.format(dateFormat)
```

Don't use a static method to get the request in the service. If you do this, the alarm bells and flashing red lights will be joined by a violent shaking of the building you're in.  Just pass it in from the controller.

**Option 3:**
Format the date in the view

```
<g:set var="formattedDate" value="${g.formatDate(date: date)}" />
```

This is undoubtedly the cleanest method, but sometimes you're not using templates to return the output.

**Option 4:**

Use a tagLib and output from the controller after getting the data in the service.
e.g.

```
def model = service.getModel()
def output = myTagLib.myOutputHtmlMethod(model)
```

Then you can use g.formatDate in myTagLib

Comment: There are other options, formatting the date in the controller as mentioned above is one of them.